# Odd error when adding target: 'es5' to webpack.config.js file

Tags: javascript, web, webpack, babeljs

I have been trying to learn full stack web development and began learning webpack and babel. I was starting very slow, I haven't even added any non development dependencies like react or electron yet. I am just attempting to understand the basics of how babel and webpack operate when used in conjunction. I have gotten my webpack file and it worked perfectly fine before I added the `target: "es5",` line. It now looks like:

```
module.exports = {
  entry: './src/index.js',
  target: "es5",
  module: {
    rules: [{
      test: /\.js$/,
      use: {
        loader: 'babel-loader'
      }
    }]
  }
}
```

which worked perfectly fine when it was converting the files to es5, but the webpack syntax used newer versions. When attempting to make webpack convert its own syntax to es5 - via the `target: "es5",` line - by running the command `npx webpack --config webpack.config.js --mode=development` it gives me the following error.

```
Error: For the selected environment is no default script chunk format available:
JSONP Array push can be chosen when 'document' or 'importScripts' is available.
CommonJs exports can be chosen when 'require' or node builtins are available.
Select an appropriate 'target' to allow selecting one by default, or specify the 'output.chunkFormat' directly.
```

Why am I getting this error and how is it remedied?

I should also note that I do have a separate file called babel.config.js that includes the following.

```
module.exports = {
  presets: ["@babel/preset-env"]
}
```